# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^2 + 1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Please, explain, how to calculate this limit?

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^2 + 1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{k}{k^2+1} < \dfrac{1}{k}$$, and

$$0 \leq \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k} \leq  \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\ln n + 1}{n}$$

The Limit in the right side is $0$ .

Squeeze theorem says the limit is $0$ .

Comment: +1 motivation and effort, and good answer as a quite new member....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use $a_n = \dfrac{n}{n^2+1}$ and Cesaro theorem, the answer should be $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = ?$. Note: I try avoid searching for duplicate in the database...